# Finding the the Maximum likelihood

Tags: probability

$$f(x;\mu) =  
\begin{cases}
  \frac{1}{3\mu^3} x^2 e^{-x/\mu} & (x>0) \\
  0 & \textrm{(otherwise)}
\end{cases}$$

I tried to get the Maximum likelihood of $\mu$ but i've blocked in the study of function

please help for the solution

Comment: Have you tried maximizing the log-liklihood function?

Comment: yes for sure , but after derivate i've seen no solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume we see $n$ observations $x_1, \ldots, x_n > 0$. Then, the log-liklihood function is:

$L(\mu) = \displaystyle\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\ln f(x_k,\mu) = \sum_{k = 1}^{n}\left[ -\ln 3 - 3\ln \mu + 2\ln x_k - \dfrac{x_k}{\mu}\right]$ $= -n\ln 3 - 3n\ln \mu + 2\displaystyle\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\ln x_k - \dfrac{1}{\mu}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}x_k$.

Now, take the derivative of $L(\mu)$ w.r.t. $\mu$, set it equal to zero, and solve for $\mu$:

$L'(\mu) = -\dfrac{3n}{\mu} + \dfrac{1}{\mu^2}\displaystyle\sum_{k = 1}^{n}x_k = 0$.

You should also make sure the result is in fact a maximum. Can you finish from here?

Comment: aah i see mistake that i did after seeing ur solution :p thank youu